# How do you ask a specific user a question about a previous question asked?

Tags: discussion

A user on here asked a question and in it they provided some insight as to what they were creating. It sounded very similar to what I am trying to figure out. How do I ask them about this in aviation SE? I tried on the specific post, but it was deleted since it doesn't answer the question. I have spent days working on this complex math problem and I would like to stop duplicating efforts if someone has already done it.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to comment on the message versus answering the question?

In any case, even if your question was deleted it doesn't mean they hadn't read it. SE does automatically send a notification to the OP when an answer is posted. After a day or two, it may be okay to send a single follow-up comment. We all occasionally miss a notification from time to time.

Comment: I think i see what you are saying. Instead of "answer", "add a comment" like I am doing now. Thank you.